# Add classes to cart items in WooCommerce Mini Cart block

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I got my self quite familiar with php and wordpress hooks etc. But now with the Gutenberg blocks in JS, i'm not getting it.

I made a simple plugin that adds some options to a product and if the product is checked some classes are added to the product. I got this fixed for the shopping cart also but the Woocommerce mini cart block i can't figure out.

This is the function for the shopping cart page:

```
// Add the "is_alcohol" class to cart items
function custom_add_cart_item_classes($class, $values, $values_key) {
    if (isset($values['data'])) {
        $product = $values['data'];

        // Check if the product is alcohol (you should determine this based on your product data).
        $is_alcohol = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'is_alcohol', true);

        if ($is_alcohol === 'yes') {
            $class .= ' is_alcohol';
        }
    }

    return $class;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'custom_add_cart_item_classes', 10, 3);
```

Can somebody help me how  i can add classes to the products in the mini cart block?

> https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-blocks/#section-18

`<tr class="wc-block-cart-items__row MY_CUSTOM_CLASS" tabindex="-1">`